# Datagrid render slow

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I am using Datagrid which has around 400-500 rows and its very slow. I am using .NET 4.5 and have tried using the property

```
VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizingWhenGrouping="True"
```

but no effect. Could someone please help me as to why this property is not working for me?

my datagrid xaml is

```
    <DataGrid VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizingWhenGrouping="True"  VirtualizingPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling" Name="DetailsDlg"  Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" MinWidth="300" MinHeight="500"  IsReadOnly="True" CanUserSortColumns="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" SelectionMode="Single" ItemsSource="{Binding UnitDataTable, Mode=OneWay}"/>
```

I have tried removing VirtualizingPanel.VirtualizationMode but no effect. It is the rendering that takes time not loading of my DataTable

My ViewModel

```
    private object _SelectedItem;
    public object SelectedItem
    {
        get
        {
            return _SelectedItem;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != _SelectedItem)
            {
                _SelectedItem = value;

                OnPropertyChanged("SelectedItem");
                UpdateDataTable(_SelectedItem);
            }
        }
    }

    private DataTable _UnitDataTable;
    public DataTable UnitDataTable
    {
        get
        {
            return _UnitDataTable;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != _UnitDataTable)
            {
                _UnitDataTable = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("UnitDataTable");
            }
        }
    }

    private void UpdateDataTable(object SelectedObject)
    {
        unittable = new DataTable("Unit Table");

        if (SelectedObject != null)
        {
            string temp = ORBATTool.SelectedUnit.ToString();

            List<MUnit> tempUnitList = new List<MUnit>();

            if (SelectedObject is UnitTree)
            {                    
                AddChildUnitsToList(SelectedObject as UnitTree, tempUnitList);       
            }

            else if (SelectedObject is MUnit)
            {
                tempUnitList.Add(SelectedObject as MUnit);
            }
            List<string> resList = CreateResList(tempUnitList);



            unittable.Columns.Add(iNet_Localization.Cultures.Resources.Callsign);
            unittable.Columns.Add(iNet_Localization.Cultures.Resources.Size);
            unittable.Columns.Add(iNet_Localization.Cultures.Resources.Strength);
            unittable.Columns.Add(iNet_Localization.Cultures.Resources.Position);

            foreach (string st in resList)
            {
                string colname = st.Replace("(", "|");
                colname = colname.Replace(")", "|");
                unittable.Columns.Add(colname);
            }

            int firstRes = 4;
            int[] scoreArray = new int[resList.Count + firstRes];                

            foreach (MUnit unit in tempUnitList)
            {                   
                DataRow dr = unittable.NewRow();

                dr[0] = unit.Callsign;
                dr[1] = resourceSet.GetString(unit.Size,true);
                dr[2] = unit.Strength;
                dr[3] = unit.PositionInCurrentGSP;
                int resindex = firstRes;

                foreach (string res in resList)
                {
                    string resstring = string.Empty;
                    foreach (var unitres in unit.Resources)
                    {
                        if (unitres.Value == res)
                        {
                            resstring = unitres.Key;
                        }
                    }                        

                    // Calculate Res 'Scores'
                    try
                    {
                        if (resstring != string.Empty)
                        {
                            int numVal = Convert.ToInt32(resstring);
                            scoreArray[resindex] = scoreArray[resindex] + numVal;
                        }
                    }
                    catch (FormatException e)
                    {
                        // ignore value?
                    }
                    dr[resindex++] = resstring;
                }

                unittable.Rows.Add(dr);
            }
            UnitDataTable = unittable;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Please show us the model-objects which are in your Itemssource

Comment: I have updated the question with the ViewModel

Comment: how are you fetching the datatable. did you check the retreival time?

Comment: Yes. My data in UpdateDataTable is fetched in no time. It is the render of UnitDataTable that takes time.

Answer (score 0):

These few things can help in performance improvement .

- if you you having large number of rows and columns in your datagrid, you should use custom paging.
- remove outer scroll viewer if applied.

  ```
  EnableColumnVirtualization = true
  EnableRowVirtualization = true
  ItemsSource="{Binding MyDataTable, IsAysnc=True}
  ```